# How to crop a square image from normalized vertices

Tags: python-3.x, google-vision

I'm using this code to identify tops and bottoms of photographs:
( as of now I only have it working for tops. one thing at a time ;) )

```
def get_file(path):
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    
    for images in os.listdir(path):
        # # Loads the image into memory
        with io.open(images, "rb") as image_file:
            content = image_file.read()

        image = types.Image(content=content)

        objects = client.object_localization(image=image).localized_object_annotations

        im = Image.open(images)
        width, height = im.size

        print("Number of objects found: {}".format(len(objects)))
        for object_ in objects:
            if object_.name == "Top":
                print("Top")
                l1 = object_.bounding_poly.normalized_vertices[0].x
                l2 = object_.bounding_poly.normalized_vertices[0].y
                l3 = object_.bounding_poly.normalized_vertices[2].x
                l4 = object_.bounding_poly.normalized_vertices[3].y
                left = l1 * width
                top = l2 * height
                right = l3 * width
                bottom = l4 * height
        
                im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
                im.save('new_test_cropped.tif', 'tiff')
                
                im.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Script to automatically crop images based on google vision predictions of 'tops' and 'bottoms'")
    parser.add_argument('--path', help='Include the path to the images folder')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    get_file(args.path)
```

The images are opened, clothing is identified, and then the images are cropped and saved to a new file. (granted as of now they are being overwritten within the loop, but I'll fix that later)
What I cant figure out, is how to make the crop a 1:1 ratio. I need to save them out as square-cropped to be put on our website.
I'll be honest, the normalized_vertices make no sense to me. Hence why I'm having trouble.

Starting image:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `l2 = object_.bounding_poly.normalized_vertices[1].y` instead of `l2 = object_.bounding_poly.normalized_vertices[0].y`? Not that it'll make a difference for a horizontal rectangular crop, but still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Normalized" means the coordinates are divided by the width or height of the image, so normalized coordinates `[1, 0.5]` would indicate all the way (1) across the image and halfway down (0.5).

For a 1:1 aspect ratio you want `right - left` to be equal to `top - bottom`. So you want to find out which dimension (width or height) you need to increase, and by how much.

```
height = abs(top - bottom)
width = abs(right - left)
extrawidth = max(0, height - width)
extraheight = max(0, width - height)
```

If `height > width`, we want to increase width but not height. Since `height - width > 0`, the correct value will go into `extrawidth`. But because `width - height < 0`, `extraheight` will be `0`.

Now let's say we want to increase the dimensions of our image symmetrically around the original crop rectangle.

```
top -= extraheight // 2
bottom += extraheight // 2
left -= extrawidth // 2
right += extrawidth // 2
```

And finally, do the crop:

```
im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
```

For your image, let's say you get `left = 93`, `right = 215`, `top = 49`, and `bottom = 205`

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: so I don't even need to use the vertices?

Comment: You need to use the vertices to obtain `left`, `right`, etc in the first place. Then you operate only in "absolute coordinates" using `left`, `right`, etc. instead of "normalized coordinates" using the vertices. I hardcoded those values because I don't have the library you're using to get the vertices. My code would go between your lines  `bottom = l4 * height` and `im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))` @Michael

Comment: I figured that out after I commented :)
Thank you so much! You f*n rock!

Comment: If you're still reading this - any idea how to handle exceeding the file size limit with PIL?

Comment: Never mind - it's a google api error! Ugh.
Thanks again @Pranav!